# Left anti join in groups

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that has two columns `a` and `b` where the values in the `b` column are `a` subset of the values in the a column. For instance:

```
df
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
|  2|  1|
|  3|  2|
+---+---+
```

I’d like to produce a dataframe with columns `a` and `anti_b` where the values in the `anti_b` column are any values from the `a` column such that `a!=anti_b` and the row `(a,anti_b)` does not appear in the original dataframe. So in the above dataframe, the result should be:

```
anti df
+---+------+
|  a|anti_b|
+---+------+
|  3|     1|
|  2|     3|
+---+------+
```

This can be accomplished with a `crossJoin` and a call to `array_contains`, but it’s extremely slow and inefficient. **Does anyone know of a better spark idiom to accomplish this, something like `anti_join`?**

Here is the inefficient example using a small dataframe so you can see what I’m after:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas.DataFrame(numpy.array(
[[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[3,2]]),columns=['a','b']))

crossed_df = df.select('a').withColumnRenamed('a','_a').distinct().crossJoin(df.select('a').withColumnRenamed('a','anti_b').distinct()).where(pyspark.sql.functions.col('_a')!=pyspark.sql.functions.col('anti_b'))
anti_df = df.groupBy(
  'a'
).agg(
  pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list('b').alias('bs')
).join(
  crossed_df,
  on=((pyspark.sql.functions.col('a')==pyspark.sql.functions.col('_a'))&(~pyspark.sql.functions.expr('array_contains(bs,anti_b)'))),
  how='inner'
).select(
  'a','anti_b'
)

print('df')
df.show()

print('anti df')
anti_df.show()
```

**Edit:** This also works, but it's not much faster:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas.DataFrame(numpy.array(
[[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[3,2]]),columns=['a','b']))

crossed_df = df.select('a').distinct().crossJoin(df.select('a').withColumnRenamed('a','b').distinct()).where(pyspark.sql.functions.col('a')!=pyspark.sql.functions.col('b'))
anti_df = crossed_df.join(
  df,
  on=['a','b'],
  how='left_anti'
)
```

Comment: What version of Spark?

Comment: @pault 2.4.1, but I can upgrade to 2.4.4 if needed.

Comment: what is the size of `df.select('a').distinct()`?

Comment: @jxc Currently about 100k.

Answer (score -1):

This should be better than what you have:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set, expr

anti_df = df.groupBy("a").agg(collect_set("b").alias("bs")).alias("l")\
    .join(df.alias("r"), on=expr("NOT array_contains(l.bs, r.b)"))\
    .where("l.a != r.b")\
    .selectExpr("l.a", "r.b AS anti_b")\

anti_df.show()
#+---+------+
#|  a|anti_b|
#+---+------+
#|  3|     1|
#|  2|     3|
#+---+------+
```

If you compare this execution plan with your methods, you'll see that is better (because you can swap out `distinct` for `collect_set`), but it still has a Cartesian product.

```
anti_df.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*(3) Project [a#0, b#294 AS anti_b#308]
#+- CartesianProduct (NOT (a#0 = b#294) && NOT array_contains(bs#288, b#294))
#   :- *(1) Filter isnotnull(a#0)
#   :  +- ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[a#0], functions=[collect_set(b#1, 0, 0)])
#   :     +- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#0, 200)
#   :        +- ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[a#0], functions=[partial_collect_set(b#1, 0, 0)])
#   :           +- Scan ExistingRDD[a#0,b#1]
#   +- *(2) Project [b#294]
#      +- *(2) Filter isnotnull(b#294)
#         +- Scan ExistingRDD[a#293,b#294]
```

However, I don't think there's any way to avoid the Cartesian product for this particular problem without more information.